# bootstrap css conflict with gmap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Help me,

i'm try to show mini map on my website using jquery from http://gmap3.net/en/pages/5-getting-started/#downloading-gmap3-12

but it conflicting with my bootstrap css
the map control won't show.

see the image for detail. [image] ***see the red circle***

how to solve this?

Comment: found the answer here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169198/google-maps-doesnt-show-zoom-controls][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169198/google-maps-doesnt-show-zoom-controls

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS which will override the image max-width of bootstrap. Try to set this rule only for the map something like `#my-map img`.

```
img {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```